# How to unit test that the correct implementation of an interface is used?

Tags: unit-testing

I have this problem with unit testing for years. Unit testing should test isolated units, that is, if we use interface/implementation vocabulary, it should test concrete implementation classes. Fine, let's do it. In a code that is the client of the interface, one should mock the interface to suit the tests. That's OK, let us do it where possible, too.

But then, in the productions code, there is some place where the actual implementation class is instantiated and used as the-instance-that-implements the interface. It may be factory methods, it can be somewhere else.

I have the problem how to actually test this glue between those two, correctly tested in isolation, layers. Using variants of `instance of` is brittle - not to say, the creator of the actual instance may be "smart" and choose different implementation based on circumstances. Even if not, it creates that instance using some configuration around.

So far, I either do not unit test in strict manner (so I do not do `new Foo(directa, directb)`, but `createApp(indirectA, indirectB).getFoo()` instead), but that may not be proper unit testing. That does not test all the implementations, that test those-implementations-app-uses. Other approach I may see is to make tests of Foo implementation parametric, having a factory method `makeFoo(a,b)` and create subclasses for each implementations as well as one which creates those instances via an actual app.

Do you know of a good way on how to approach this?

In other words, the question may be simply "How to (unit) test glue code?"

Comment: Can you keep all the unit tests in a separate project, so that test-only implementations can't be imported when building the real thing?

Comment: @Doval I don't understand.

Comment: You said: *"But then, in the productions code, there is some place where the actual implementation class is instantiated and used as the-instance-that-implements the interface. I have the problem how to actually test this glue between those two, correctly tested in isolation, layers.*" Rather than testing that the "actual implementation" is used, can you organize your project so you can't import any of the mocks when building the application?

Comment: I don't have the problem of "not importing the mocks". I have the problem of "test that the thing instantiated is the right one". Especially in the duck-typing world. So when there is some `this.foo = new Bar(this.baz, this.quux)` somewhere in the glue code, how to sanely test the this.foo is actually the good object implementing all the behaviour that is wanted, initialized properly, etc.

Comment: I don't have the global understanding of that matter to write a perfect answer, so I'll forward you [this talk](https://vimeo.com/80533536). This guy explains the problem you have and provide the solution

Comment: @herby I guess I don't understand your problem. What does "the good object" mean, and why do you have objects that are not good? If you're using duck typing you shouldn't care which implementation gets passed in.

Comment: @Doval Yes, but I should test that some object was actually created, and that that object is correct. The question is, how to test the glue code that creates and setups it, when you already have full coverage on the class itself, but how to test the code that may look like `var client = new FooClient(); client.connect(this.config.foo);`. This code, that actually creates the pieces and glues them, should be tested, too; the question is, how.

Comment: @ThomasRuiz Interesting one. Using the vocabulary of it, I realized I rarely write other than contract tests - but without its counterpart, so @jbrains would not accept them as those, since there is no matching, but I do not like to overmock everything, so I mostly skip them. But that sweet spot, the place where the objects to fulfill the contract is instantiated, is not covered. In an aftermath, it looks that the problem is the `new FooImpl(bar)` in Java/JavaScript. If it was `createFoo(bar)` consistently, I could run my contract test against its result, not against `new FooImpl(testbar)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an aftermath of https://vimeo.com/80533536 talk of @jbrains, posted by @ThomasRuiz, I came to this conclusion:

- Write contract tests (the talk has strict definition of them, I have loose one: "tests that only use public API of the class").
- Stop using `new FooImpl(fooConfig)` to create implementations of "instance that fulfills `Foo` contract", instead, make it mandatory for your code to have `createFoo(fooConfig)` factory method to instantiate the `Foo` contract worker (maybe it should be called `hireFoo` ;-) ).
- Your contract tests should test against `client.createFoo(testFooConfig)`. It may be you end up with the need of client being `higherClient.createBar(...)` itself. This is the weak spot of the whole thing. Maybe I should ask.jbrains.ca ... :-\

EDIT: Talked with @jbrains. The result is:

- Your constructors should not create the collaborators. Ideally, they get them injected, like `new Foo(collab1, collab2);`
- Applying this to the extreme, it ends up with creating all (!!!) collaborators up front in the topmost layer. See http://blog.thecodewhisperer.com/2011/12/07/refactor-your-way-to-a-dependency-injection-container. See it as an app config.
- Citation "`new A(new B(new E()), new C(new F(), new G()), new D())` is fine. `A` creating `B`, which creates `E` (and so on) causes problems", in https://twitter.com/jbrains/status/570974691013337089.

I finally know what actual dependency injection is and why it is important (your code becomes actually testable and decoupled, all the glue code is in one place and is the only untested piece).

Answer (score 9):

The way you test glue code is by running an [integration test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing).

> The purpose of integration testing is to verify functional, performance, and reliability requirements placed on major design items. These "design items", i.e. assemblages (or groups of units), are exercised through their interfaces using black box testing, success and error cases being simulated via appropriate parameter and data inputs.
>
> Simulated usage of shared data areas and inter-process communication is tested and individual subsystems are exercised through their input interface. Test cases are constructed to test whether all the components within assemblages interact correctly, for example across procedure calls or process activations, and this is done after testing individual modules, i.e. unit testing.

Comment: That's duplication, though. You essentially copy same tests you did in unit tests (not always, of course, but for some scenarios, when the number of combinations in sub-part is big, integration test must test them all, albeit in complicated setup).

Comment: I never said it was easy.  Good testing requires effort.  See also http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/274481

Comment: Testing that should "drive the process" and / or "give early feedback" should not be that hard, or it loses its meaning. Testing for testing correctness, there yes.

Answer (score 7):

[There are two ways of writing unit tests.](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UnitTest.html)  Most people think there's only one way.  If you use sociable tests, you can test the glue as part of the test.

[image]

Comment: That's what I mentioned by `createApp(indirectA, indirectB).getFoo()` just did not call it sociable test. That's what I basically do now.

Comment: Except that depending on the other units, you're no longer _unit_ testing. If that first box is `main`, you're effectively "unit testing" your whole app. Yes, I've seen people do that - and I've seen them wonder why their tests took days and were fragile, unreliable, useless things.

Comment: @Telastyn iaw solitary tests are unit tests and sociable tests are integration tests

Comment: @jk. you and Martin Fowler should duke it out.  Because his article specifically says they're unit tests.

Comment: @Telastyn I believe people who write Sociable Tests still use test doubles.  They just don't do it at *every* collaborator.

Answer (score 2):

> But then, in the productions code, there is some place where the actual implementation class is instantiated and used as the-instance-that-implements the interface. It may be factory methods, it can be somewhere else.
>
> How do you test that?

There are three scenarios here.

The first is that you don't care about the instance used. Some code internally uses some concrete instance to do its work and that code is already "unit" sized. That's great. Ignore the implementation detail and test the inputs/outputs.

The second is some sort of factory. For some given inputs, you get the proper output. That is an easy to test unit like any other unit - provide some inputs (tending towards boundary conditions) and make sure the output is correct. Usually `instanceof` is sufficient, but you could check behavior of the resultant object if it's simple/obvious/unchanging.

The third is configuration sort of code. It might be configuration itself, or it might be hardcoded inputs to more general code. In almost all of my apps for example, all `main` does is specify concrete instances and glue them together. I do not unit test that code, and I do not recommend you do either.

Why? Because it provides no benefit. Unit testing exists to provide early, clear signs that something is wrong. In my experience, if you screwed up your concrete instantiation (and have a relatively sane architecture) then simply running the app provides a quick, clear and cheap indicator if things are configured correctly or not.

Comment: Yes, I was concerned about the third case. I have some feeling towards "do not test it and make it as obvious as possible" as well. Just wasn't that sure. I would still have bad feelings a bit and will feel the need for some smoke test anyway.